# Hiding parent text with pseudo element absolutely positioned

Tags: css

I have a list of `<a>` tags containing icons and hidden text. I am having an issue with extra spacing above these tags.

I have narrowed it down to the `position: absolute` entry of the pseudo element.

How do I remove this extra space while maintaining the absolute positioning?

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzcrq7vc/))

```css
a {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  font-size: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 20px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>TEST</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: by adding  `overflow: hidden;`  to `ul { }` the problem will not be solved ? I'm not sure how you want it to look like exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to your `li` elements.

```
li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzcrq7vc/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top` on the `<a>` element.

```css
a {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  font-size: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
a {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  font-size: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 20px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>TEST</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This answer was also correct though a different approach. I marked the first one posted. Thanks